# Adding a "processing" page between requests

Tags: c#, webforms

- .NET 4.51 WebForms

I would like to introduce a "please wait" page between page requests. So if I have a user on Page1.aspx and they click a button then show this processing page until a response comes back from the server which could be Page1.aspx again or say a redirect to Page2.aspx.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript on the `onclick`-event on all links, and in the handler of the event display a div with the text "please wait".

Using jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("body").append("<div class='loading-div'>Please wait</div>");
});
```

Good if you don't add the div more than once. The div will disappear when the new page is rendered.

Comment: I can see how that would work. Just wondering if there is a way to achieve the same effect using the ASP.NET page life cycle?

Comment: No there is not, since you will not be able to send anything to the client intil the whole request is processed. The only option is to trigger something client-side.

Comment: But to make this really work I would hake to target buttons, any custom script that may already be attached to OnClick events that cause navigation away etc. Hmmm this seems harder than I thought and more error prone.

Answer (score 0):

If it's requests to the same page, use an UpdatePanel around your content and an UpdateProgress control to display the animation.